# How to Set Call Back For Enter key of GtkTextView?

Tags: gtk

Really fed-up how can i set call back on enter key of GtkTextView Widget.
For which event i can listen?

Thanks.

Comment: It is common practice that if you think an answer is good that you should upvote it as well as accept it.

Comment: I am doing it for every Question that i had asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gboolean on_key_press (GtkWidget * widget, GdkEventKey* pKey,gpointer userdata){

   if (pKey->type == GDK_KEY_PRESS){

        g_print("%i\n", pKey->keyval);

          switch (pKey->keyval)
        {
            case GDK_Enter :
                gtk_main_quit ();
            break;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Callback can be registered using :

```
GtkWidget *view;
view = gtk_text_view_new();
g_signal_connect(view, "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), NULL);
```

**

Please visit [this page](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/stable/x182.html) for more information :

**

Comment: Oh! got it. do you know how we can change text size and color of GtkTextView?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `GDK_Enter` but I got an error

```
error: ‘GDK_ENTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Using `GDK_Return` fixed things

Answer (score 0):

In my program (python) I have

```
renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
renderer.set_property("size", 30000)
renderer.set_property('cell-background', 'yellow')
```

This sets the size and background.

You need to look for something similar.